# Calculate % using OVER() for each row in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, partitioning

I needed guidance with a question on how to calculate percentage between two cells on each row. I am on SQL Server 2012. Below is the structure of my current dataset.

```
Customer_Number    Price_Last_Year      Price_Today
---------------------------------------------------
909523                   154               190
20175808                 154               100
21808187                 154               190
22792798                 184               284
23256155                 154               230
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to include an additional column that calculates the percentage of `(Price_Today)/Price_Last_Year)` for each specific row. I am using the windowing `OVER()` function and it has not worked properly.

This is how I want the my new dataset to look like:

```
Customer_Number Price_Last_Year     Price_Today     Percentage_AS ofToday%
909523                   154               190                 23.3%
20175808                 154                  100             -35.1%
21808187                 154               190                 23.3%
22792798                 184               284                 54.3%
23256155                 154               230                 49.3%
```

This my query for the percentage calculation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Customer_Number,
   Price_Last_Year,
   Price_Today,
   [Percentage AS of Today%]=SUM(Price_Today)100.0/(Price_Last_Year) OVER()
FROM 
   tabl2 a
GROUP BY 
   Customer_Number, Price_Today, Price_Last_Year
```

I have tried a number of variations for the percentage `OVER()` calculation. I even tried something like `[Percentage AS of Today%]=SUM(Price_Today)100.0/(Price_Last_Year) OVER() (PARTITION BY Customer_Number)`, and it throws an error.

How can I calculate the percentage using `OVER()` for each row?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like there's any reason for you to be using over, or sum.  Just divide: `Price_Today / Price_Last_Year`. BTW, your math looks a little funny, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your calculation is between two columns of the same row you don't need an `over()` clause or a `group by` clause - just divide the two. Subtracting this from 1 and multiplying by 100 should give you a nice percentage representation:

```
SELECT Customer_Number, 
       Price_Last_Year, 
       Price_Today, 
       (1 - (Price_Today/Price_Last_Year)) * 100 AS [Percentage AS of Today%]
FROM   tabl2
```

Comment: Thank you. I learnt something from you regarding when to use OVER().

Answer (score 1):

Given the data you supplied it looks like you have way overcomplicated this.  The OVER seems unnecessary as does the GROUP BY.  I think this will do what you want.

```
SELECT Customer_Number 
     , Price_Last_Year
     , Price_Today
     , (Price_Today)*100.0/(Price_Last_Year) - 100 as [Percentage AS of Today%]    
FROM tabl2 a
```